# reverse engineer binary encoded data

Tags: binaryfiles

Is there a general approach? It doesn't appear to be encrypted, and I know the file must contain numeric tabular data of some kind:

```
$ od -tc filename.hobo | head
0000000    H   O   B   O 210  \r 004  \0  \0 001   d 210 035 004  \0  \0
0000020  001   c 210   " 035 001  \0  \0 001 035       q   -  \0   $ 070
0000040    8   E 001   d 377 377 235 220  \0  \0 001  \0  \0  \v  \f    
0000060  030 002 210   5 032 001 003 003 001  \0  \a  \0  \0  \0  \0  \a
0000100   \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 005 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 210
0000120    c 001  \0 210 033 002  \a    ҈  ** 034 002  \0 001 210 001 002
0000140  017 033 210 002 002 001 035 210 003 002 001  \n 210 004 032   O
0000160    n   s   e   t       C   o   m   p   u   t   e   r       C   o
0000200    r   p   o   r   a   t   i   o   n 210 005 024   H   O   B   O
0000220        U   2   3   -   0   0   1       T   e   m   p   /   R   H
```

Comment: If you don't know what actual data is stored there - it would be impossible. If you know - possible with some degree of confidence. If you can alter it - then even with higher confidence.

Comment: @zerkms I do know at least some of the data (have a CSV export of a table) in the file. Can you point me from "possible with some degree of confidence" to step 1?

Comment: Yes - if you know original data - simply try to find it in that dump? I'd use `xxd` though to visualise it